# How to set the location of the cursor. (p5.js JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, p5.js, cursor-position

I would like to set the cursors location. I've tried really off the wall solutions such as...

```
MouseX = (location in X axis);
MouseY = (location in Y axis);
```

However this doesn't work (obviously), I'm really not sure how to move the cursors position with my script, does anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can due to the browsers security constrains. I know in Java you can accomplish such functionality but in JavaScript, I don't think it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. [`mouseX`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mouseX) and [`mouseY`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mouseY) are system variables that can only be used to retrieve the value of the cursor position. Changing them will not change the cursor position. You could look into the [pointerlock API](https://w3c.github.io/pointerlock/), which is [supported in most browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointerlock).

Comment: I agree with the first two words of this answer. But saying that `mouseX` and `mouseY` are read-only isn't quite true, as you can certainly set their values. It's just that setting their values doesn't actually change the position of the cursor.

Comment: @KevinWorkman fair enough. I don't know the technical details behind how `mouse[XY]` are implemented, so I didn't want to say you could set their values if they are implemented using a getter that wouldn't appear to persist your values.

Comment: They're just variables. Nothing too special about them.